# import Elementor site setting programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

When we develop a custom theme, It's helpful to use custom color / custom typography setting from Elementor Site Settings. But It's not import we setup Demo import settings. ( Using One click Demo import or other ) Only way i saw import/export site kit from elementor tools. but is it possible to do programmatically? I want to inlcude the function in one click Demo import function, so when oneclick demo import will run successfully it will import automatically.